# Image moving to next page and text is not. Why? how to fix it

Tags: graphics, floats

I am writing a thesis. I have big figures, about a page long. I want them to come after certain text/paragraph, but they are moving way ahead from that text and going to several pages.

Figure is in PDF format.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{figure_path.pdf}
\caption{Phase-I: Machine Count dashboards}
\label{fig:mc}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: you need  to show your code but I would guess you have the image in a `figure` environment, the only function of which is to allow it to be moved to a later page

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: `[h]` means do not allow the figure at the top or bottom or on a page on its own as you have removed the default `tbp` possibilities, so latex has few options and it is likely to be held to a `\clearpage` flushes floats at the end of a chapter

Comment: Hi can you tell me some code, which I can write to that Photo should be where it is, black pages can be left, but location of figure should not change??